# Why does matplotlib change color intensities in displayed image?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to write some codes for image processing, but I'm facing a weird issue.

I want to show the following image, already converted to grayscale of range 0 to 255:

https://ibb.co/tqTPcpq

To do this, I wrote this code

```
img_low_cont = plt.imread("hamster.png") 
plt.imshow(img_low_cont, cmap='gray')
```

But it's showing another version of my image:

https://ibb.co/Xzw3WYB

I've tried to figure out why it's hapenning, but I'm not sure. Do anyone have any idea?

I'm sorry for not giving more details, this is exactly all that I have of info. I had some hours of researching for the answear, but didn't found anything usefull.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation of the `vmin` and `vmax` arguments of matplotlib's [`imshow`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.imshow.html) function gives a vital clue as to what's happening:

> **vmin**, **vmax** : scalar, optional
>
> When using scalar data and no explicit norm, vmin and vmax define the data range that the colormap covers. By default, the colormap covers the complete value range of the supplied data. vmin, vmax are ignored if the norm parameter is used.

In other words: by default the intensity of single-color images gets rescaled. To prevent this from happening use the input arguments `v=0` and `vmax=255`, like so:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
img_low_cont = plt.imread("hamster.png") 
plt.imshow(img_low_cont, cmap='gray', vmin=0, vmax=255)
```

Comment: It worked! Thanks for the help. I need to pay more atention to the documentation.

Comment: Great. In that case, you can mark this answer as the [accepted answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Comment: Done! Thanks again